# How to test whether a progress bar appears and disappears on response using react-native and jest testing framework?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

Basically, I want to call onLoginPressed event from login-test file and check whether showProcessbar is set to true or not and on response it is set to false.

```
var Login = require('../Login');//

describe('Check Login', () => {
  Login.onLoginPressed();
  it('process bar is shown', () => {
    expect(showProgress).toBe(true);
  });

  it('process bar is gone', () => {
    expect(showProgress).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is `showProgress` set in Login component's state?